# Why truncate table does not change the Last DDL Date?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, toad

When I run the following code, I notice that  `Last DDL Date`  has not changed.

```
 execute immediate 'truncate table my_table';
```

What is the problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

The thing is :

> **Table is empty.**
>
> When a table is empty your truncate ddl does not
> change the Last DDL Date.

Answer (score 4):

The `truncate` table only truncates the table if it is not empty.

If the table is empty then it is not truncated when you execute the `truncate table` command.

See the demo here:

```
SQL> select OBJECT_NAME, LAST_DDL_TIME from user_objects where OBJECT_NAME = 'CONTR';

OBJECT_NAME  LAST_DDL_TIME
------------ --------------------
CONTR        13-nov-2019 11:45:53

SQL> truncate table CONTR; -- empty table

Table truncated.

SQL> select OBJECT_NAME, LAST_DDL_TIME from user_objects where OBJECT_NAME = 'CONTR';

OBJECT_NAME  LAST_DDL_TIME
------------ --------------------
CONTR        13-nov-2019 11:45:53

SQL> INSERT INTO CONTR VALUES (1,1,1,1); -- filling values in the table

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> truncate table CONTR;

Table truncated.

SQL> select OBJECT_NAME, LAST_DDL_TIME from user_objects where OBJECT_NAME = 'CONTR';

OBJECT_NAME  LAST_DDL_TIME
------------ --------------------
CONTR        13-nov-2019 11:47:46

SQL> -- time is changed now
```

Cheers!!